# Where are manual locations for $configs?

Tags: ubuntu, command, man, rsyslog

In Ubuntu, when I run the command `man rsyslog.conf`, a manual page comes up. So I tried to find the location of this man page by `whereis -m rsyslog.conf`, but it didn't give me any results. Should I use another command for $config mans' locations? Where are these man pages stored in Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ask `man` where it's finding the man page.

```
$ man -w rsyslog.conf
/usr/share/man/man5/rsyslog.conf.5.gz
```

The `whereis` utility does know to look there:

```
$ whereis -m xfs.5
xfs: /usr/share/man/man5/xfs.5.gz
```

So why doesn't it find `rsyslog.conf`?

```
$ whereis -m rsyslog.conf
rsyslog:
```

The fact that the line begins with `rsyslog:` and not `rsyslog.conf:` is a hint. It's because `whereis` [ignores the extension](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/v2.34/misc-utils/whereis.c#L470) of what you ask it to find.

```
$ whereis -m xfs.1
xfs: /usr/share/man/man5/xfs.5.gz
```

And when `whereis` is looking at available files, it [ignores compression extensions](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/v2.34/misc-utils/whereis.c#L401), and allows the actual file to have one extra extension (plus a few other things that aren't relevant here). So when it's told to look for `xfs.5`, it actually looks for `xfs`, but allows `xfs.5.gz` as a match (it would also allow `xfs`, `xfs.42`, `xfs.gz`, etc.). When it's told to look for `rsyslog.conf`, it actually looks for `rsyslog`, and it would allow `rsyslog.conf.gz` or `rsyslog.5.gz` but not `rsyslog.conf.5.gz`. If you told it to look for `rsyslog.conf.5`, it would find the man page (but it would even find a man page in another section).

While `whereis` conveniently groups looking for executables, manual pages and source code in one place, it's less reliable than other tools because it has quirky lookup rules and only looks in hard-coded places.

- To look for an executable in your current executable search path (`$PATH`), use the `type` shell builtin.
- To look for a man page in your current man page search path (`$MANPATH` or deduced from `$PATH` plus a system configuration), use `man -w` (or `man -wa` in case there are multiple matches).
- To look for a file anywhere on the system, use [`locate`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix)).
- To look for a file in an Ubuntu package even if you haven't installed that package, use [`apt-file search`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file).

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, `dpkg -L <package>` will tell you all files shipped with this package. If you don't find the man pages in there, then you can often find it in `<package>-doc`

For `rsyslog`:

```
$ dpkg -L rsyslog | grep man
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rsyslog/mmanon.so
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man5
/usr/share/man/man5/rsyslog.conf.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man8
/usr/share/man/man8/rsyslogd.8.gz
```

You can look at the raw `*.gz` with:

```
$ gunzip -c /usr/share/man/man5/rsyslog.conf.5.gz
.TH RSYSLOG.CONF 5 "22 October 2012" "Version 7.2.0" "Linux System Administration"
.SH NAME
rsyslog.conf \- rsyslogd(8) configuration file
.SH DESCRIPTION
The
.I rsyslog.conf
file is the main configuration file for the
.BR rsyslogd (8)
which logs system messages on *nix systems.  This file specifies rules
for logging.  For special features see the
.BR rsyslogd (8)
manpage. Rsyslog.conf is backward-compatible with sysklogd's syslog.conf file. So if you migrate
from sysklogd you can rename it and it should work.
...
```

To answer your more general question "Where are manual locations for configurations", these are in chapter 5 (`/usr/share/man/man5/`).  If we look at the output of [`man man`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/man) (don't google that), we get:

```
       The table below shows the section numbers of the manual followed by the types of pages they contain.

       1   Executable programs or shell commands
       2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
       3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
       4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
       5   File formats and conventions, e.g. /etc/passwd
       6   Games
       7   Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
       8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
       9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```